# How can I gain read/write access to a folder (and contents recursively) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions

My Windows 10 machine sometimes denies me access to folders. (Screenshot below.) I don't understand why because according to Properties > Security I have "full control."

I tried clicking "Edit" as indicated, and also "Advanced." I also tried Properties > Read-only (uncheck & apply to contents). No matter what settings I apply, the folder remains denied.

How can I make it so I use the folder normally?

Is there a command I can run as Administrator that will fix the folder?

[image]

I tried running [this tool on Microsoft's support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17590/automatically-diagnose-and-repair-windows-file-and-folder-problems). It reported that it found and fixed problems, but had no apparent effect.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your folder path is `C:\Folder`. To allow all permissions for current user, run these commands as administrator:

```
Takeown /F "C:\Folder" /R /D Y 
Icacls "C:\Folder" /grant %USERNAME%:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

To allow only read *and* write permission, run these commands as administrator:

```
Takeown /F "C:\Folder" /R /D Y 
Icacls "C:\Folder" /grant %USERNAME%:(RD,WD,AD) /T
```

To get further information read [takeown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown) and [icacls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls) command details from Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Thanks. `takeown` returned "SUCCESS" messages for everything in the dir, but `icalcs` errored out "Access is denied". I checked the docs you linked & tried running it with /c (among many other things). When I did that it returned a separate "Access is denied" for each subdir. How is it possible to be denied access if I'm logged in as Administrator? Is there a level of authority greater than Admin in Windows? Any other things I could try?

Comment: @Nafine Do not log in as administrator. Log in as a normal user. Try to replace `%USERNAME%` with `Everyone` (if you want) for both pair. Then run with `%USERNAME%`.